# Beacon Android Application. Unable to Loop

Tags: java, android, altbeacon

I'm trying to develop a Beacon Android application using AltBeacon specification whereby the application will start the service, stop, and repeat the service again. As of now, I'm able to start and stop the services however, I'm unable to repeat to the very first 'If' statement. May I know what am I missing?

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            // Enter details
            if (major.getText().toString().equals("") || minor.getText().toString().equals(""))
            {
                SuperActivityToast.create(getActivity(), new Style(), Style.TYPE_BUTTON)
                        .setText("Please fill Major and Minor details!")
                        .setDuration(Style.DURATION_LONG)
                        .setFrame(Style.FRAME_LOLLIPOP)
                        .setColor(PaletteUtils.getSolidColor(PaletteUtils.MATERIAL_PURPLE))
                        .setAnimations(Style.ANIMATIONS_POP).show();

            }
            // If user has entered
            {
                final Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
                        .setId1(uuid1)
                        .setId2(major.getText().toString())
                        .setId3(minor.getText().toString())
                        .setManufacturer(0x0118)
                        .setTxPower(-69)
                        .setRssi(-66)
                        .setBluetoothName("Hall 1")
                        .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[] {0l}))
                        .build();

                BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
                        .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25");

                // Making the instance of BeaconTransmitter
                final BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getActivity(), beaconParser);

                // Start Advertising the above Beacon Object
                beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);

                // Toasting the message that beacon succesfully made
                SuperActivityToast.create(getActivity(), new Style(), Style.TYPE_BUTTON)
                        .setText("Successfully Started!")
                        .setDuration(Style.DURATION_LONG)
                        .setFrame(Style.FRAME_LOLLIPOP)
                        .setColor(PaletteUtils.getSolidColor(PaletteUtils.MATERIAL_PURPLE))
                        .setAnimations(Style.ANIMATIONS_POP).show();

                // Making some animation and changing the text of button
                AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1,0);
                alphaAnimation.setDuration(1500);
                alphaAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
                alphaAnimation.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
                b1.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
                b1.setText("Stop Broadcasting");

                b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        beaconTransmitter.stopAdvertising();
                        b1.setText("Broadcast Beacon");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I suggest adding Log.d statements to your code to see the value of major and minor.  This will help you trace the state  changes that affect the control flow.

Comment: I'll try to add those!